# Trying to find a normal form (through O($\epsilon^2$) of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, differential-forms

I have the following differential equation:

${\dot{z}} = -iz + \epsilon [\frac{z-z*}{2} + \frac{(z-z*)^2}{24}]$

(the parameter $z$ is complex and i is the classic imaginary $\sqrt{-1}$)

I'm trying to use a Lie transformation in order to find the normal form of this equation approximated through O($\epsilon^2$), in order to get a simpler version of my original equation (simplifies my Physical model).

I'm having trouble with the Lie transformations (of the kind $z = e^{\epsilon G}w$) because I'm self-taught on the matter. Can someone help me with the specific problem, or maybe guide me on how to do it myself?